# Comparing values in one same string

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

In my script, Im getting data from website, like that:

```
content=$(wget 10.0.1.5:8000/currentsong?sid=1 -q -O -);
```

It's basicaly song information on shoutcast server. But there is the problem:
I like to do: If the new value dont match the old value in the string, do something. Like that:

```
if [ $content.new != $content.old ]; then
        echo "New song info there.."
else
        echo "NOTHING"
fi
```

How can I do that?

**EDIT:** I forgot say, the script will run in **loop**.

Comment: Where is the old content stored?

Comment: @DisplayName The problem is it's not stored I don't know how to store the old value.

Comment: then you have to store it in some file or something.

Comment: @DisplayName I don't know how to do that real-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like

```
content=$(wget 10.0.1.5:8000/currentsong?sid=1 -q -O 
content_old=$(cat /tmp/content.old)
if [ "$content" != "$content_old" ]; then
        echo "New song info there.."
else
        echo "NOTHING"
fi
echo $content > /tmp/content.old
```

Comment: Thank you, I already done it, but my problem was in $string and "$string"

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that if $string is empty then your compare fails because bash just doesn't see anything there.  If you quote it then bash will see the empty string.  One of the may weird quirks of the shell :)